# SSRS 2016 still renders reports that look like 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

We are upgrading to SSRS 2016 from 2008 R2. When we run the reports that were created in 2008 R2 in 2016 they render the same. However the web portal for 2016 looks new. Is there something that needs to be done to the report or to the URL calling it so it renders in the more modern 2016 SSRS look/feel?

Comment: The only thing that should be different is the command bar (contains controls & params).  The report itself isn't going to be magically redesigned because you updated the server.

Comment: Can you imagine the feedback Microsoft would get if an upgrade of SSRS all of a sudden changed the look/feel of existing reports? Users would be calling for someone's head! *You* make the report look the way you want it to look, not SSRS.

Comment: I recommend changing all of the headers to cornflower blue and making the table borders .5 black. That will make it look new and slick. Probably.

Comment: OK I suppose it was my ignorance based on the the UI update on the rest of SSRS that it would propagate to the report.